# Cant call method or use bean with camel

Tags: xml, spring, routes, apache-camel, javabeans

I'm very new to Camel, but basically, I've got a bean with a function called populate. Camel is not able to call this method, nor does it activate anything in the route it seems. I dont know what I'm doing wrong, can someone help?

I tried using populate() and populate in my route, I also tried getting rid of @Handler.

the Logger does not get called either, I just put it there to see what happens.

**Here is my route, then I'll post my bean.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">


 <bean id="mockSql" class="tutorial.simple.route.MockSql"/>

 <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <log loggingLevel="DEBUG" message="logger" id="123" customId="true"/>
    <to uri="bean:mockSql?method=populate()"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
</beans>
```

**heres my bean:**

```
package tutorial.simple.route;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.camel.Handler;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class MockSql {
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("mockSql");

    public MockSql(){
        log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        log.debug("constructed mock sql");

    }
    @Handler
    public ArrayList populate(){
    ArrayList <HashMap> ary = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap();
    HashMap<String, String> hm2 = new HashMap();
    hm.put("n1", "j1");
    hm2.put("n2", "j2");

    ary.add(hm);
    ary.add(hm2);

    log.debug("populated mock sql");
    return ary;
}


}
```

**output:**

[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] MainSupport                    INFO  Apache Camel 2.12.0.redhat-610379 starting
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] mockSql                        DEBUG constructed mock sql
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.12.0.redhat-610379 (CamelContext: camel) is starting
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] ManagedManagementStrategy      INFO  JMX is enabled
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] DefaultTypeConverter           INFO  Loaded 176 type converters
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance.
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://start]
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.12.0.redhat-610379 (CamelContext: camel) started in 0.324 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `direct` endpoint can be triggeted only from another route, for example like this:

```
<route>
    <from uri="<other endpoint>"/>
    ...
    <to uri="direct:start"/>
</route>
```

so in your case the route is never triggered.